# Preserve vertical dimension with numpy.mean()

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I am calculating the mean of an array row-wise while the array can have one or more rows. Some values can be `NaN` and within the array, either the entire row is `NaN` or not.

When my array looks like

```
[[  3.  nan  nan  nan  nan  nan  nan]
 [  1.  nan  nan  nan  nan  nan  nan]]
```

the result of `numpy.mean(.., axis=0)` is `[  2.  nan  nan  nan  nan  nan  nan]`.

However, when I have only one column array like

```
[  5.  nan  nan  nan  nan  nan  nan]
```

then the result of `numpy.mean(.., axis=0)` is only `nan`.

But I want `[  5.  nan  nan  nan  nan  nan  nan]`. How can I achieve this? Do I have to use an if-condition?

Comment: are you sure, that your second array is a two dimensional array? It won't work, if it's a one-dimensional vector. `a = np.array([5, np.nan, np.nan], ndmin=2)`, `np.mean(a, axis=0)` gives the expected result for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wrap your array in `atleast_2d`.  The problem array will be reshaped to `[[5 nan ...]]`, a 1row 2d array.

```
np.mean(np.atleast_2d(myarray), axis=0)
```

`np.matrix` does something similar, but with more baggage, including preservation of the 2 dimensions in the output.  `np.mean` can also preserve dimensions if needed.

Answer (score 0):

You could convert the array to a matrix to ensure it has the required two dimensions:

```
In [5]: arr = np.array([5., np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan])

In [6]: np.mean(arr, axis=0)
Out[6]: nan

In [7]: np.mean(np.matrix(arr), axis=0)
Out[7]: matrix([[  5.,  nan,  nan,  nan,  nan,  nan,  nan]])
```

This will work with both of your examples (note, however, that it produces a 2D output).